# embed shape in xlink with raphael

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, xlink

I have actively (and for hours) search an answer for this on the web but couldn't find as I dare ask.
I work with Raphael.js that is a library to create SVG by programming in JS. I would like to embed a shape in a link.

In SVG a namespace is added to the SVG tag to signal the use of xlink:

```
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

Then for instance it is possible to create a shape embedded in a link by (this excellent blog tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/a-element.html ):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <a xlink:href="/svg/index.html" target="_top">
        <rect x="10" y="20" width="75" height="30" style="stroke: #333366; fill: #6666cc"/>
    </a>
</svg>

</body></html>
```

Here is the Fiddle : [little rectangle](https://jsfiddle.net/samdisbien/ngv2nz5g/)

With the Raphael library (and in my example jquery) the code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="raphael.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="my-canvas"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

var paper = Raphael('my-canvas', 500, 300);      
jq('svg').attr('xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');

var rec = paper.rect(10, 20, 75, 30);
rec.attr('fill', '#6666cc');
rec.attr('stroke', '#333366');

var l = jq('<a xlink:href="#"></a>');      
jq(rec.node).wrap(l);

</script>
</html>
```

And here is the fiddle: [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/samdisbien/u3jpc878/4/)

The problem is that is does not work. This code executed until the line:

```
rec.attr('stroke', '#333366');
```

show the shape perfectly drawn but after that ... erased. 
An other interesting point is that Firefox show that the DOM document is as wished after execution of the whole code i.e two lines later (that I cannot show here for my reputation is not sufficient apparently...) but it is easily reproduce. That is to say the I clearly see in the DOM nodes:

```
<a xlink:href="/svg/index.html" target="_top">
    <rect x="10" y="20" width="75" height="30" style="stroke: #333366; fill: #6666cc"></rect>
</a>
```

If somebody could enlighten me on my mistake i would be glad.

Many thanks